# where to type command sudo apt-get install-f?

Tags: command-line, apt

Since I've never run into this kind of problem before with an error message, this broken count<0.  Left clicking on package manager is no different than right clicking. (what error message says to do)  What this site says to do is put in command sudo apt-get install-f. Where do I put that command as I have tried different places without anything happening.  I'm just into basic computer use so this is a problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

You are asked to use the "command line interface" (CLI). You do that by opening a terminal, which can be done by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. There, enter the command `sudo apt-get install -f` (mind the space after `install`) and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

You will be asked for your password, which will *not* appear on the screen, not even as *****, as you might expect.

Then, the `apt` software installation program will start, which will try to sort out what you need to get a fully working system.